# How to use JAX-RS annotations for a custom REST method?

Tags: rest, jax-rs, quarkus, resteasy

I would like to add a custom method `search` to a resource `books` ([more about custom methods](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/custom_methods)):

```
/books:search
```

I created a class:

```
public class BooksResource {

   @POST
   @Path("/books:search")
   public String search() {
      return "The best book";
   }

}
```

But, after invoking of `/books:search` I am getting a response code `404`.

How could I annotate the `BooksResource` correctly?

Comment: Have you tried using `@Path("")` on the class as well?

Comment: Quarkus offers a lot of really useful documentation about this topic: https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive, https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json

Comment: @nik0x1 cool! I added the comment as an answer so future readers can find it without reading the comments. Please accept it for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `@Path("")` on your class as well